# Авторизация на сайте с помощью Python

Tags: python, запрос, requests, авторизация, веб-сайт

Учусь работе с сайтами с помощью скриптов. Ради проверки решил написать программу для авторизации на stackoverflow. Результатом работы становится страница "а не робот ли вы часом?". Как можно решить данную проблему?

```
import requests
import fake_useragent

link = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login?"
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random

header = {
    'user-agent': user
}

data = {
    'email': '#email',
    'password': '#password',
}

response = requests.post(link, data=data, headers=header).text
print(response)
```

Comment: Либо отрисовывайте капчу на клиенте (у себя) и решайте, либо юзайте капчесолв (но это А: плохо по отношению к SO B: Не рационально в данном случае)

Comment: @icYFTL , там вроде как капча в виде чекбокса. Как можно подобное "распознать"?

Comment: в каком плане распознать? Капчесолв это сервис, где пол Китая решает Вам капчи вручную.

Comment: Ну как минимум вы ещё fkey забываете передавать

Comment: @andreymal , fkey? Что это?

Comment: @icYFTL , что-то я ничего не нашел о капчесолве. Не подскажите куда копать (ссылку или пример)?

Comment: Откройте исходный код формы логина и вы увидите там fkey

Comment: @Roman, https://rucaptcha.com/ , например

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в нехватке данных при передаче запросов.

```
import requests
import fake_useragent

link = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login?"
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random

header = {
    'user-agent': user
}

data = {
    'fkey': 'fkey',
    'ssrc': 'ssrc',
    'email': 'email',
    'password': 'password'
}

response = requests.post(link, data=data, headers=header).text
print(response)
```